# VB.net clicking a submit button using Web Browser

Tags: vb.net, browser

I want to click the submit button of the webpage i am displaying in my Web Browser but it seems not to work at all here is my code:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("image")
```

i was basing on the html code of the button i want to click which is:

```
<div class="buttonRow forward">
<input type="image" src="includes/templates/template_default/buttons/english/button_send.gif" alt="Send Now" title=" Send Now ">
</div>
```

did i miss something? i really need help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this property

```
  Webbrowser.AllowNavigation = True
```

Comment: i cannot edit the html code as i am just basing a sample website that has a submit button. That is the only html code that was referring to the button.